# D3 Sunburst - How to map custom color to path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I’m currently building a D3 Sunburst `Vue` component and I’m using the npm package `vue-d3-sunburst` for that. The documentation for the package can be found here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-d3-sunburst

The documentation says there is a `get-category-for-color` function which is used to map an item and its color like this:
`(nodeD3: Object) => category: Number | String By default use the node name`

I’m completely having a moment here and just can’t figure out how to get the color value of each node applied to each path and I'm wondering if anybody can help?

```js
const {
  sunburst,
  highlightOnHover
} = window['vue-d3-sunburst'];
window.Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/**
 * FlavorWheel Component.
 */
new window.Vue({
  el: "#app",
  name: "flavor-wheel",
  components: {
    highlightOnHover,
    sunburst,
  },
  props: {
    /**
     * Cupping notes.
     */
    cuppingNotes: {
      type: Object,
      default () {
        return {
          name: "base",
          children: [{
              name: "Fruity",
              color: "#da1f24",
              children: [{
                  name: "Berry",
                  color: "#de4b52",
                  children: [{
                      name: "Blackberry",
                      color: "#3e0316",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                    {
                      name: "Blueberry",
                      color: "#6469af",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                  ],
                },
                {
                  name: "Dried fruit",
                  color: "#ca4a44",
                  children: [{
                      name: "Raisin",
                      color: "#b43b54",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                    {
                      name: "Prune",
                      color: "#a4456e",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                  ],
                },
                {
                  name: "Other fruit",
                  color: "#f2684b",
                  children: [{
                      name: "Cherry",
                      color: "#e73351",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                    {
                      name: "Pineapple",
                      color: "#f99a18",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                    {
                      name: "Peach",
                      color: "#f68a5b",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              name: "Sour/Fermented",
              color: "#ebb20f",
              children: [{
                name: "Sour",
                color: "#e1c217",
                children: [{
                    name: "Alcohol/Fermented",
                    color: "#9fa81a",
                    size: 1,
                  },
                  {
                    name: "Citric acid",
                    color: "#f9ee01",
                    size: 1,
                  },
                ],
              }, ],
            },
          ],
        };
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      data: this.cuppingNotes,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * Function used to map an item and its color
     */
    getColorValue() {},
  },
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <sunburst
        class="flavor-wheel"
        :data="data"
        :showLabels="true"
        :centralCircleRelativeSize="10"
        :getCategoryForColor="getColorValue()"
      >
        <template slot-scope="{ on, actions }">
          <highlightOnHover v-bind="{ on, actions }" />
        </template>
      </sunburst>
    </div>
  `
});
```

```css
.flavor-wheel {
  width: 500px !important;
  height: 500px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flavor-wheel text {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-d3-sunburst@1.9.1/dist/vue-d3-sunburst.umd.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-d3-sunburst@1.9.1/dist/vue-d3-sunburst.css">


<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Thank you, I ended up switching to codesandbox where I'm now able to show the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sunburst-custom-color-59kpp?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Great! I've updated your question to have the example work inline, so we can guarantee that it will stay available in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not incredibly familiar with Vue, but I'm pretty sure the problem is as follows:

Instead of calling the function in the HTML, you need to pass it as a property. The difference is that if you add the brackets, the *result* of the function will be passed to VueJS, not the function itself. Then, you'll be able to access the arguments of the function just the way you'd expect.

---

**EDIT**

The name `getCategoryForColor` should have tipped me off, but what happens is actually not what you expect. The `getCategoryForColor` function expects to receive any string or value that represents that "category" to which the cell belongs. Those categories are then mapped to a `colorScale` function which makes sure a valid color is generated for every category, and that elements with the same category get the same value.

You actually jumped the gun a little on that bit, because you already specified what the color should be! So in order to fix that part, I also overwrote the color scheme to simply return whatever it was passed. Now, the correct colors are applied.

```js
const {
  sunburst,
  highlightOnHover
} = window['vue-d3-sunburst'];
window.Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/**
 * FlavorWheel Component.
 */
new window.Vue({
  el: "#app",
  name: "flavor-wheel",
  components: {
    highlightOnHover,
    sunburst,
  },
  props: {
    /**
     * Cupping notes.
     */
    cuppingNotes: {
      type: Object,
      default () {
        return {
          name: "base",
          children: [{
              name: "Fruity",
              color: "#da1f24",
              children: [{
                  name: "Berry",
                  color: "#de4b52",
                  children: [{
                      name: "Blackberry",
                      color: "#3e0316",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                    {
                      name: "Blueberry",
                      color: "#6469af",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                  ],
                },
                {
                  name: "Dried fruit",
                  color: "#ca4a44",
                  children: [{
                      name: "Raisin",
                      color: "#b43b54",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                    {
                      name: "Prune",
                      color: "#a4456e",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                  ],
                },
                {
                  name: "Other fruit",
                  color: "#f2684b",
                  children: [{
                      name: "Cherry",
                      color: "#e73351",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                    {
                      name: "Pineapple",
                      color: "#f99a18",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                    {
                      name: "Peach",
                      color: "#f68a5b",
                      size: 1,
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              name: "Sour/Fermented",
              color: "#ebb20f",
              children: [{
                name: "Sour",
                color: "#e1c217",
                children: [{
                    name: "Alcohol/Fermented",
                    color: "#9fa81a",
                    size: 1,
                  },
                  {
                    name: "Citric acid",
                    color: "#f9ee01",
                    size: 1,
                  },
                ],
              }, ],
            },
          ],
        };
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      data: this.cuppingNotes,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * Function used to map an item and its color
     */
    getColorValue(v) {
      return v.color;
    },
    colorScale(col) {
      return col;
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <sunburst
        class="flavor-wheel"
        :data="data"
        :showLabels="true"
        :centralCircleRelativeSize="10"
        :getCategoryForColor="getColorValue"
        :colorScale="colorScale"
      >
        <template slot-scope="{ on, actions }">
          <highlightOnHover v-bind="{ on, actions }" />
        </template>
      </sunburst>
    </div>
  `
});
```

```css
.flavor-wheel {
  width: 500px !important;
  height: 500px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flavor-wheel text {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-d3-sunburst@1.9.1/dist/vue-d3-sunburst.umd.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-d3-sunburst@1.9.1/dist/vue-d3-sunburst.css">


<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked - thank you so much for all your help and the detailed explanation!